# Solving a trig equation in a specific range

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, assumptions, trigonometry

I want to define a function as such

```
g[n_] := Assuming[1<=x<=2, NSolve[n==-2 Cos[Pi x], x]]
```

However the result comes out as a conditional expression, for example, `g[1]` returns

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[0.31831 (-2.0944 + 6.28319 C[1]), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
 {x -> ConditionalExpression[0.31831 ( 2.0944 + 6.28319 C[1]), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

Mathematica seems to be ignoring my application of `Assuming`. I get the same result using `Refine`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: there is no `g` in `NSolve[n==-2 Cos[Pi x], x]` so I am not sure what is this assumption is doing there. It has no effect. When I run your code, I also do not get  the `g->` I get `x->` result.  Did you copy things correctly?

Comment: That was a typo, it should be `x` in the assumption.

Comment: Ok, does `NSolve[n == -2 Cos[Pi x] && 1 <= x <= 2, x]` give you what you want? note, you have no assumptions on `n` there. You could also use `Solve`

Comment: Yes that works, thank you, I didn't realize I could do that but that makes perfect sense. Also `FindRoot` worked together with `Refine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[g]

g[n_] = x /. Solve[n == -2 Cos[Pi x] && 1 <= x <= 2, x][[1]]

(* ConditionalExpression[(2 π - ArcCos[-(n/2)])/π, -2 < n < 2] *)
```

Restrict the definition of `g[n]` to `-2 < n < 2` and provide exact output for exact input, i.e., use `Solve` for exact input and `NSolve` for inexact input.

```
Clear[g]

g[n_] := (x /. 
    If[Precision[n] === Infinity, Solve, NSolve][
      n == -2 Cos[Pi x] && 1 <= x <= 2, x][[1]]) /; -2 < n < 2
```

For exact input

```
g /@ Range[-2, 2, 1/2] // FullSimplify

(* {g[-2], 2 - ArcCos[3/4]/π, 5/3, 2 - ArcSec[4]/π, 3/2, 
 2 - ArcSec[-4]/π, 4/3, 2 - ArcCos[-(3/4)]/π, g[2]} *)

% // N

(* {g[-2.], 1.76995, 1.66667, 1.58043, 1.5, 1.41957, 1.33333, 1.23005, g[2.]} *)
```

For inexact input

```
g /@ Range[-2., 2., 0.5]

(* {g[-2.], 1.76995, 1.66667, 1.58043, 1.5, 1.41957, 1.33333, 1.23005, g[2.]} *)

% == %%

(* True *)

Plot[g[n], {n, -2.25, 2.25}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!